# Deity Suggestions

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, religions-and-deities, drow

the character I'm making for my next campaign is a female drow cleric to Lolth. She believes wholeheartedly that Lolth is a good goddess. Eventually, she will face the truth that Lolth is actually terrible, and she will go on a Soul Searching Road Trip in between campaigns. When this happens, what god or goddess should she then be sworn to? (She's a Twilight cleric if that helps any.)

Comment: This sounds like quite a setting-specific question, so what setting are we talking about?

Comment: I'm not voting to close, but I do think this verbiage could be cleaned up to be more in keeping with how we usually do things here. Hopefully, someone will come along with some good suggestions before I think of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One such deity described in Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes is **Eilistraee**. She seems a perfect fit provided that she is present in whatever setting your adventure takes place in.

> Eilistraee is a god of moonlight, song, dance, and, most important,
> the rejection of the evil ways of Lolth. Drow who feel like outsiders
> in their society, who react with disgust to the evils perpetrated by
> their kind, who come to the surface and fall in love with the
> stars-these are the ones who might be pleased to hear Eilistraee's
> call. If they respond to it by going to the surface and staying there,
> Eilistraee offers no guarantee of their safety and no promise of
> acceptance in the world above. But she opens her followers' hearts to
> the wonder of the nature in the night, and her songs and signs can
> show a drow how to persevere in that alien environment.

Though again, this is all highly setting-dependent, in Exandria for example I'd recommend **The Moonweaver** instead.

Comment: tbh, I was going to vote to close this question (opinion based?), but your answer seems to fit with the question like a puzzle piece and has convinced me otherwise.

Comment: @goodguy5 I agree, the question as it's phrased now does leave a lot to opinion, maybe if it was changed to "Are there any deities specifically made for apostate Lolth clerics?", as it seems clear to me that's what OP is really after.